# Remove test score via iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center

On [WWDC session 605](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-605/), it is said test data can be management via iTunesConnect. But I currently can't find how to achieve this.
It is live or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You should follow these steps:

- Login in iTunesConnect with appropriate AppleID (the one associated with your iTunesConnect account).
- Go to MyApps
- Click on your app
- Click on Features

[image: features button]

- Choose GameCenter (among other features) in left side menu
- From dropdown menu located in right part of the screen choose "Manage scores and players"

[image: dropdown menu]

From there, choose the leaderboard you want to manage and click on "manage" button. All scores will show up and you can choose what scores you want to remove, or which player to block.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed that you are trying to delete all test data before submitting an app to the Store instead of managing already submitted game.

In that case, just chose "Delete test data" from dropdown menu from the picture above. This action can take about 24 hours to happen. So be patient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok thanks. The dropdown menu do not display on my account.

Comment: Answered my question.  Thanks!